# How to create a line graph in crystal reports using string value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a problem creating a line graph.

I have a string like "1,3,4,5,6,10,2,3". How to make it into graph?

[image: a line graph corresponding to the string "1,3,4,5,6,10,2,3"]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create or use a Crystal Reports UFL (User Function Library).
Ken Hamady maintains a list of 3rd-party UFLs [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).

Here is an image demonstrating how your string can be converted to a line or column chart by using a function from one of these UFLs. The function generates a chart image file (on-the-fly). The '***Graphic Location***' expression of a dummy image is simply set to the path of the resulting image file.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way without using UFL?